# Foreign key links

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm unsure how to link my tables:
Users(registration details of users),
Personal (personal details of users),
Academic (academic details of users),
Language (language details of users),
Thesis (Thesis details of users),
Referees (Referee details of users),
Addresses (Address details of users)

Should I have an 'id' field in each of the tables so I can join them all? Plus a primary key of of e.g. Academic_ID. Which would I set as auto inc?

Once the users registers, my system should link information from the users table to all other information they enter for the other tables.

I hope this makes sense
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a field named `"user_id"` to your Users table. Then, in each table you wish to join to Users add a field with the same name. 
This way, you could make a query like:

```
select * from Users, Personnal
where Users.user_id = Personnal.user_id
```

which would join your results the way you want. About your second question, yes you can/should add a unique autoincrement field like personnal_id and so on. Good practice and makes you record unique.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do an `id` field as the primary key (autoincrement), then you can do a unique key on lets say `user_id` (in each table) and then u can use `user_id` to link the tables.

Comment: so I wouldn't put user_id in each table, I would use a different name for e.g. academic table = academic_id. how would they link with different names?

Comment: what's your current table structure?!?

Comment: For table users (PK-id, UK-users_id), Personal (PK-id, UK-personal_id) and so on